# LINQ to XML: parsing simple XML entry

Tags: c#, xml, linq

First time with LINQ to XML, climbing the learning curve...

I am looking for the smoothest way how to retrieve and convert the data from XML file, with as little if-else and, god forbid, try-catch statements as possible. I really hate all that lengthy code just to retrieve single value from the doc.

Having said this, I am looking for a fail-safe solution, that would work not break if the structure of the XML doc has unexpectedly changed. In such case, I'd expect that null value is retrieved so I could check for it later in code.

Here's my XML doc:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Entry>
  <IntField>11</IntField>
  <StringField>String data</StringField>
  <DateTimeField>28/03/2013 18:10:02</DateTimeField>
</Entry>
```

I am looking for code where I retrieve one value per row of code, ie:

```
myXMLdoc = XDocument.Load("sourceFile.xml");
int? myIntField = (smart linq query that retrieves&converts the value, with fallback of null);
string? myStringField = (smart linq query etc.);
DateTime? myDateTimeField = (smart linq query etc.);
if (myIntField == null)
{
    // Complain that structure of the XML doc is bad
}
```

Perhaps my expectations that LINQ can do this are naïve, but, well, having written lumps and lumps of XPath expressions and if-else statements for trivial pretty XML processing, I have accrued some bitterness about it. So I turn to LINQ with big hopes indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although LINQ2XML by itself lacks the necessary "magic", it offers enough "underpinning" for you to build the code yourself. Here is an example that shows you how to read an `int?` from an element at arbitrary depth (assuming that the path is unique, of course):

```
public static class LinqExt {
    public static int? ReadInt(this XElement e, string path, int? fallback = null) {
        foreach (var name in path.Split('/')) {
            e = e.Element(name);
            if (e == null) {
                return fallback;
            }
        }
        int val;
        return int.TryParse(e.Value, out val) ? val : fallback;
    }
}
```

You can use this extension method as follows:

```
var myXMLdoc = XDocument.Load("sourceFile.xml");
var intVal = myXMLdoc.Root.ReadInt("IntField");
```

The method would work even with some nesting, for example if your document looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Entry>
  <Nested1>
      <Nested2>
          <IntField>11</IntField>
      </Nested2>
  </Nested1>
</Entry>
```

you would get the value like this:

```
var intVal = myXMLdoc.Root.ReadInt("Nested1/Nested2/IntField");
```